# Uber API Deep Link Android

Tags: javascript, html, uber-api

The Deep link to embed pickup and dropoff locations work on iOS, but when they are tested on Android, they do not work. On Android instead of embedding pickup and dropoff locations, the deep link simply opens the Uber app. I think there may be an issue with my Javascript, as I think the logic and actual deep link are working properly.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Emails</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {

        // Parse the user agent to determine the device
        var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null,
            isiPhone = !isiPad && ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) != null)),
            isiOS = isiPad || isiPhone,
            isAndroid = !isiOS && navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i) != null,
            isMobile = isiOS || isAndroid,
            isDesktop = !isMobile;

        // Define all the potential redirection Urls
        var deepLink = 'uber://?action=setPickup&pickup=my_location&dropoff%5Blatitude%5D=33.784685&dropoff%5Blongitude%5D=-84.4121&dropoff%5Bnickname%5D=Apartment%20of%20Paul%20Jump&dropoff%5Bformatted_address%5D=1100%20Howell%20Mill%20RD%2C%20Atlanta%2C%20GA%2030318',
            appStoreUrl = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/uber/id368677368',
            androidIntentUrl = 'intent://uber/#Intent;package=com.ubercab;scheme=uber;end',
            muberDotCom = 'http://m.uber.com';

        // Handle each case with a seamless fallback to the application store on mobile devices
        if (isiOS) {
          window.location = deepLink;
          setTimeout(function() { window.location = appStoreUrl; }, 25);
        } else if (isAndroid) {
          window.location = androidIntentUrl;
        } else if (isDesktop) {
          window.location = muberDotCom;
        }

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you haven't even defined the variables you want, where are the pickup and dropoff locations in this URI:

```
androidIntentUrl = 'intent://uber/#Intent;package=com.ubercab;scheme=uber;end',
```

Just use `deepLink` for when `isAndroid` is `true`, like:

```
if (isiOS) {
      window.location = deepLink;
      setTimeout(function() { window.location = appStoreUrl; }, 25);
} else if (isAndroid) {
      window.location = deepLink;
      setTimeout(function() { window.location = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubercab&hl=en_GB'; }, 25);
} else if (isDesktop) {
      window.location = muberDotCom;
}
```

Comment: How would I add pickup_latitude=37.775818&pickup_longitude=-122.418028&dropoff_latitude=37.802374&dropoff_longitude=-122.405818 to `androidIntentUrl = 'intent://uber/#Intent;package=com.ubercab;scheme=uber;end'`?